# TestNG: No tests found for given includes: [RunCucumberTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, testng

I've been trying to run some Cucumber tests using TestNG in IntelliJ and am having trouble with the runner. I'm able to launch each test individually but when I try to use a runner to run all the tests together I get the following error:
[image: Image of error saying "No tests found for given includes: RunCucumberTest"]

The structure of the project is as follows:

```
|src
|
|---|test
|   |
|   |---|java
|   |   |
|   |   |---|stepdefs
|   |   |
|   |   |---|RunCucumberTest.java
|   |
|   |---|resources
|       |
|       |---|cucumber
|
|---|build.gradle
```

And the build.gradle file is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.8.1'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:4.8.1'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.8.1'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.5'
    testImplementation('io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.3.2')
    testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.5'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.11.1'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:7.12.1'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20230227'
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.8.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.6.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.6.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'cucumber-tests'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}
```

What could be causing this issue with running the tests, and how could I fix it?